# Dynamic Form and AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

We have a dynamic Form being rendered based on database configurations. I am using code as mentioned in the below fiddle

But am not able to get the value of the checkbox element selected. Please guide me through this.
I am using checklist-model for Checkbox Elements.

```
 <label ng-repeat="cCheck in form.color">
  <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="outputs[form.databaseAttr]" checklist-    value="cCheck" ng-init="outputs[form.databaseAttr] = form.defaultValue"> {{cCheck}} <br>
</label>
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/surajnaik821986/fg3967yo/)

Please let me know if we have anybetter way of handling Dynamic Forms. Something like jQuery Serialize where we pass the formId and get all elements from the form.

Comment: please post the relevant code in question not in external link. JSfiddle is great for demos but isn't a substiute for the actual problem code

Comment: @charlietfl That is the fiddle I have created, trying to mention the way I am trying to use angular with dynamic forms. It works well except with Checkboxes. Please guide me through this

Comment: what part of posting your code in question did you not understand?

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated the JSFiddle    http://jsfiddle.net/surajnaik821986/fg3967yo/       if you select multiple values and click save the Checkbox values are not being captured correctly as in the fiddle

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your trying to accomplish (and isn't working) but maybe [this](https://github.com/McNull/angular-febworms) will help you out abit. We use it to create and render dynamic forms. It contains a checkboxfield template from which you might wanna borrow some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a checklist-directive developed to solve the checkbox problem. You can download [check-list.js](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.checklist-model/0.1.3/checklist-model.min.js) and add it as the module dependency as following:

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('example', ["checklist-model"]);
```

So, in your html, you should use `checklist-model` and `checklist-value` instead of `ng-model` and `ng-value` respectively:

```
<div ng-switch-when="checkbox">
    <br>{{form.text}} <br>
    <label ng-repeat="cCheck in form.color">
      <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="outputs[form.databaseAttr]" checklist-value="cCheck" ng-init="outputs[form.databaseAttr] = form.defaultValue"> {{cCheck}} <br>
  </label>
</div>
```

[Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/fg3967yo/2/).

**EDIT:** In order to set default values of the checkbox, you can put the values that you want into the `outputs[from.databaseAttr]` array. In your case, defaultValue:

```
{
    text: 'select mutiple colors',
    databaseAttr: 'checkbox',
    type: 'checkbox',
    color: ['red', 'blue', 'black'], 
    defaultValue: ['blue'] // <-- blue is set as default
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fg3967yo/4/).

Comment: Thanks I was using checklist-model as mentioned in the question. Forgot to add the module dependency :(. Anyways how do we default select the checkbox in the above fiddle ??